# setting a linear gradient above a background image in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can i set up a linear gradient above a background image in Bootstrap?
i have tried many ways, but i can't figure out whats happening and i can't see the gradient. it is supposed that the gredient comes after the image, but again nothing happens, the only thing i see is the image itself.

```
#promo {
margin: 50px auto 50px;
background-image: url(images/promo.jpg), linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1) 20%, rgba(100,51,51,0.6) 86%, rgba(51,51,51,0.8) 100%);
opacity: 0.5;
height: 500px;
```

}

```
<section id="promo">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: The CSS is correct and will work fine. We need to see your HTML or a demo because that's where the problem could be.

Comment: @Harry i did post the html element that contains all of that. should i post the whole document?

Comment: Well, it probably shouldn't have an `opacity` on it...that will affect everything in the div.

Comment: the opacity isn't the problem i removed it. i cant explain it, when i remove the image and set only the gradient, it works just fine, and vice versa when i remove the gradient the image works fine, the problem is when want to display both of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the images in the wrong order:

Per [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds)

> With CSS3, you can apply multiple backgrounds to elements. These are layered atop one another with the **first background you provide on top and the last background listed in the back**. Only the last background can include a background color.

```css
#promo {
  background-image: 
    /* top image*/
    linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 20%, rgba(100, 51, 51, 0.6) 86%, rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8) 100%),
    /*bottom image*/
    url(http://lorempixel.com/image_output/abstract-q-c-500-500-3.jpg);
  height: 500px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section id="promo">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: OMG!!! isnt supposed to have the image first and the gradient second? i was pretty much sure that was the order... Thanks a lot. You saved me!!!

Comment: Nice catch. The opacity fooled me as I saw a dull image and thought it was the gradient :D

Comment: yes. that's exactly what fooled me as well. thanks a lot for your help.